# ReactJS components not rendering

Tags: reactjs, keystonejs

So, I'm using a 'KeystoneJS react generator' as a framework for my application, along with 'Material-UI' for predefined components. I'm simply just trying to seperate these components into different files, and to include them into one render function on my main application page, but they simply won't render, and am getting a blank page, with no errors in console.

As a note, I can get components to run if I were just to throw a bunch of them into my application.jsx, so I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong with my importing/exporting. Thanks a lot for the help, here the code..

```
// application.jsx
/** @jsx ReactDOM.DOM */

import ReactDOM from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import LeftNavSimpleExample from './nav-bar.jsx';
import AppBarExampleIconMenu from './app-bar.jsx';
// -------------------- components ----------------------------//

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <AppBarExampleIconMenu />
        <LeftNavSimpleExample />
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('app')
)
```

---

```
//app-bar.jsx

   /** @jsx React.DOM */

import React from 'react';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/lib/app-bar';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/lib/icon-button';
import NavigationClose from 'material-ui/lib/svg-icons/navigation/close';
import IconMenu from 'material-ui/lib/menus/icon-menu';
import MoreVertIcon from 'material-ui/lib/svg-icons/navigation/more-vert';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/lib/menus/menu-item';

const AppBarExampleIconMenu = () => (
  <AppBar
    title="Title"
    iconElementLeft={<IconButton><NavigationClose /></IconButton>}
    iconElementRight={
      <IconMenu
        iconButtonElement={
          <IconButton><MoreVertIcon /></IconButton>
        }
        targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
        anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
      >
        <MenuItem primaryText="Refresh" />
        <MenuItem primaryText="Help" />
        <MenuItem primaryText="Sign out" />
      </IconMenu>
    }
  />
);

export default AppBarExampleIconMenu;
```

---

```
//nav-bar.jsx
/** @jsx React.DOM */    
import React from 'react';
import LeftNav from 'material-ui/lib/left-nav';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/lib/menus/menu-item';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/lib/raised-button';

export default class LeftNavSimpleExample extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {open: false};
  }

  handleToggle = () => this.setState({open: !this.state.open});

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <RaisedButton
          label="Toggle LeftNav"
          onTouchTap={this.handleToggle}
        />
        <LeftNav open={this.state.open}>
          <MenuItem>Menu Item</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
        </LeftNav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Checked paths? Is it jsx or js?

Comment: What are you using to load modules? Webpack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot about this myself, but just incase anyone stumbles apon this..

I simply wasn't serving the directory that my react components were in from express.

```
app.use(express.static('files'));
```